# Showcase Image and Carousel Caption

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm experiencing a problem with the following code: 
HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About-Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact-Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="showcase">
    <div class="col-xs-12 showcase-container">
        <img src="media/tumblr_kx21pqsQBo1qaj2pio1_1280.jpg" width="1500" class="col-xs-12 showcase-img alt=""/>"
        <div class="carousel-caption showcase-title"> 
            <h1> Welcome to the Site </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default
{
margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.showcase-container {
padding-left: 0; 
padding-right: 0; 
}

.showcase-img {
padding-left: 0; 
padding-right: 0; 
}

.showcase-title {
margin: 0 auto; 
height: 320px; 
}
```

My problem is that, when I'm trying to centre the carousel caption, I'm setting the margin at the bottom and I'm able to achieve the proper effect. Now, when I resize the page, the text is moving off the screen and not resizing. Another issue comes when I want to set a background with opacity and the background is including the margin used for spacing. All of this is a dead giveaway that I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure how I should re-structure my code. Any help is most appreciated. [image: Here's what I'm working on.]

Comment: The example you've given us is not enough to reproduce the issue. Please provide links to all JS files that are used or, better yet, give us a jsFiddle to work with.

Comment: There isn't anything special in terms of JS. There is the inclusion of a script tag for jquery and bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: You also didn't give us the whole URL to your image. We need that in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @JoshuaWhitley
http://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kx21pqsQBo1qaj2pio1_1280.jpg

Comment: So, I answered the first question below but I don't understand the second. Which element are you setting a background on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the height of `.showcase-title` is set to 320px and `.showcase-title` is set to be absolutely positioned to the bottom of your image container. When you resize the browser, the image gets smaller but `.showcase-title` doesn't. Set `.showcase-title`'s height to 100% and it should fix the problem.

Comment: This went a long way toward solving my problem. I've done substantial modifications on the code since, so the above no longer applies. In the future, I'll try to change my code to make it easier to place in a codepen or jsfiddle area.